# Retornando dados adicionados em um dicionário

Tags: python, python-3.x

No meu código estou pedindo ao usuário para entrar com a nota, n° de matrícula e frequência de 2 pessoas.

Porém eu quero fazer isso usando dicionários, então eu declarei as chaves `'Nota'`, `'Matricula'` e `'Freqüência'` e armazenei na variável `aluno`. Mas na hora de exibir os dados desses dois alunos usando o método `items()` eu consigo acessar apenas ou os dados do 1° aluno ou os dados do 2° aluno, nunca os dois juntos.

A minha duvida é como exibir os dois dados, do aluno A e do Aluno B, usando os dicionários.

```
aluno = dict()

lista = []

for i in range(2):

    aluno['Nota'] = int(input(f'Digite o nota do aluno {i+1}: '))

    aluno['Matricula'] = int(input(f'Digite o numero da matricula: '))

    aluno['Frequencia'] = int(input('Digite a frequencia em porcentagem: '))

    print('--------------------------------------------')

    lista.append(aluno.copy())


for k,v in lista[1].items():

    print(k,':',  v,)
```

Comment: Olá @Giovanni, Vejo que uma solução proposta pela comunidade te ajudou, considere aceita-la, [aceitar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) uma resposta é a melhor forma de agradecer quem te ajudou, isso também ajudara quem tiver o mesmo problema e ainda mantem o site saudável pois sua pergunta deixa de ser *uma pergunta não resolvida*. -- Vale apena você dar uma olhada no nosso [Tour] =D

Comment: Giovanni, não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis. [Os votos são uma ferramenta importante no site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/112052), além de ser uma forma de reconhecer os esforços de quem perguntou e respondeu (obviamente que não é uma obrigação, mas se vc acha que as respostas foram úteis, considere votar nelas) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme já explicado pela [resposta do @Rafael](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/362940/112052), você precisa percorrer toda a lista para imprimir os dados de todos os alunos. Ao fazer `lista[1]`, você está acessando apenas o segundo aluno (já que arrays começam com o índice zero: o primeiro elemento é `lista[0]`, o segundo é `lista[1]`, etc).

Mas ainda há outros detalhes que você pode mudar, se quiser.

Em vez de criar o dicionário `aluno` fora do *loop* e fazer uma cópia toda hora, você pode criá-lo dentro do *loop*:

```
for i in range(2):
    aluno = dict() # cria um novo dicionário
    ... # lê os dados do aluno
    lista.append(aluno) # não precisa copiar
```

Ou você pode mover toda a lógica de criação de um aluno para uma função:

```
# lê os dados do aluno e retorna o dicionário com esses dados
def ler_dados_aluno(i):
    aluno = dict()
    aluno['Nota'] = int(input(f'Digite o nota do aluno {i + 1}: '))
    aluno['Matricula'] = int(input(f'Digite o numero da matricula: '))
    aluno['Frequencia'] = int(input('Digite a frequencia em porcentagem: '))
    return aluno
```

E em seguida pode criar a lista usando a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.0.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lista = [ler_dados_aluno(i) for i in range(2)]
```

O código acima é equivalente a:

```
lista = []
for i in range(2):
    lista.append(ler_dados_aluno(i))
```

Mas a *list comprehension*, além de mais sucinta, é considerada a forma mais [*pythônica*](http://pyth%C3%B4nica).

Já para imprimir a lista, aproveite que você já tem disponível as [*f-strings*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) e use-as:

```
for i, aluno in enumerate(lista):
    print(f'Dados do aluno {i + 1}:')
    for k, v in aluno.items():
        print(f'- {k} : {v}') # use a f-string para imprimir a chave e valor de uma vez
```

Note que dei uma "incrementada". Usei [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para ter, além do aluno, o respectivo índice dele na lista (só para poder imprimir "Dados do aluno X"), e também usei as *f-strings* para imprimir as informações.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa percorrer cada uma das posições da `lista` para então acessar o `k` e `v` de cada uma delas.

Na prática, o seu último `for` final ficaria assim:

```
for aluno in lista:
    for k,v in aluno.items():
        print(k,':', v)
```

Aqui eu acesso cada `aluno` na `lista`, ou seja, `lista[0]` e depois `lista[1]`, e faço o `print()` da chave `k` e do valor `v` de cada um dos `items()`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, estava realmente faltando esse for de cima, pq eu estava percorrendo a lista, e nao o aluno em cada lista, com o primeiro for eu percorro o aluno A e o aluno B e ai com o segundo for eu exibo a chave e o valor